# QGIS How to link Symbology to Named Style in Library

Tags: qgis, symbology, style

Is there any way, how to 'link' symbology to the named style in Library instead of only 'copying' the symbol definition?
Example:
 - I'm styling roads, in Symbol Selector I pick a style from Library with name i.e. 'HIGHWAY', the symbol specification is copied accordingly, ok
 - Then I open Settings->Style Manager and change the line style 'HIGHWAY' i.e from black to red
 - all the symbology created from style 'HIGHWAY' just stay black instead of changing to red
 - I want them to change if I change the 'master style HIGHWAY' in the library

Any plugin creating the 'symbology link'please?